# jQuery css selector for table

Tags: jquery, css, indexing, html-table

I'm having the following table markup:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td class=marked>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td class=marked>foo</td><td class=marked>foo</td><td class=marked>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td>foo</td><td class=marked>foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

Several cells are marked with class `marked` - how can I select all rows which have cells with class `marked`? I know how to select all marked cells but I need the rows for the selector in order to loop through them.

What I want to achieve is an array/JSON string which contains all data of all rows with cell indexes of the marked cells, which would look something like that:

```
rowdata[0] = [1];
rowdata[1] = [0,1,2];
rowdata[3] = [2];
```

Any ideas what's the easiest way to to it?

EDIT: Sorry, there was a typo, I meant class `"marked"`

Comment: `several cells are marked with class foo` Not quite. Several have the `class` 'marked', whilst some have the `text` value of 'foo'. Also, please show the code you have tried.

Comment: you can use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
var rowdata=[];

$('tr').each(function(){
   $td=$(this).find('td');
   arr=[];
   $td.each(function(index,value){
       if($(this).hasClass('marked'))
          arr.push(index);
   });
   rowdata.push(arr);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kB4M7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowdata = [];
$('table tr').each(function () {
    rowdata.push($(this).find('.marked').map(function () {
        return $(this).index();
    }).get());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S6YCA/)

Comment: This answer is in low-quality queue. Please explain your code.